# be pleasured to do something?

Tags: passive-voice

I've just received a letter where the person says: "If you are interested in, I will be pleasured to tell you more about it."

Is this passive voice, insinuating that there is a 3rd subject that will pleasure her? Or is this a legitimate way of saying that she will feel happy to tell me more about it. Also if the first case is so, does that mean that her telling me about it is actually conditioned about her being pleasured?

Comment: She's like the 3rd person that has said this, I think it might be a language barrier that's common to a certain group

Comment: That should be "pleased to."  (The way it's written can have obscene implications)

Comment: The alternative, "**It** would be a pleasure to" got the writer into this. Or is it some recent TV trope? ;)

Comment: @Kris I think this is exactly what she was trying to say, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is comically wrong.

"I will be *pleased* to tell you more about it" means "The opportunity to tell you more about it will cause me to experience pleasure".

On the other hand, "I will be *pleasured* to tell you more about it" is likely to be interpreted as "someone will give me pleasure (implying sexual gratification) as compensation/encouragement for the favour of telling you more about it", unless the reader understands the speaker is non-native or semi-literate in English.

Compare "I will be paid to tell you more about it" as an easy way to think about the latter.

EDIT: Didn't notice at first as I was focusing on the other thing, but "if you are interested *in*" is wrong as well. "If you are interested" or "if you are interested in it" would be correct.